# Bind animation input parameters to a component properties in Angular 4.2.0

Tags: angular, animation, typescript

I want to bind an animation input parameters to a component properties. Is there way to do it using new animation features of angular **4.2.0** ?

For example, I want user to set coordinates of the object and an object should move accordingly:

[image]

My **app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger,state,style,animate,transition,animation,useAnimation} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [trigger('move', [
    transition('start <=> finish', 
    useAnimation(animation([
      animate(1000, style({top: '{{x}}px',left:'{{y}}px'}))
    ], { params: { x: 100, y: 100 }})))
  ])]
})
export class AppComponent {
  moveAnimation = { value: 'start', x: 10, y: 10 };
  move() {
    this.moveAnimation.value = this.moveAnimation.value == 'finish' ? 'start' : 'finish';
  }
}
```

And **app.component.html**:

```
X:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="moveAnimation.x"><br/>
Y:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="moveAnimation.y"><br/>
<button (click)="move()">Move</button><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" [@move]="moveAnimation"></div>
</div>
```

And **app.component.css**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: have you read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/src/animation_metadata.ts#L683) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be honest, I'm not sure if the Angular Animations library is going to be the best thing for you. The way you want to use it (with parameters) seems to still be an [option issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9668). Rather than using the animations library why get the same job done with just some CSS? I've included a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wrzDMZ2vjJWKq94PX0Hy?p=preview) demo you can test.

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  moveBox = { x: 10, y: 10 };
  moveInputs = { x: 10, y: 10 };
  move() {
    this.moveBox.x = this.moveInputs.x;
    this.moveBox.y = this.moveInputs.y;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
X:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="moveInputs.x"><br/>
Y:<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="moveInputs.y"><br/>
<button (click)="move()">Move</button><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" [style.top.px]="moveBox.x" [style.left.px]="moveBox.y"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified @MichaelSolati's plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/er3K2ELi0Fz4Yc9YYtoB/) to show the Angular way using `@angular/animations`.

In template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" #movebox></div>
</div>
```

In component:

```
  animationPlayer;
  @ViewChild('movebox') moveBoxEl: ElementRef;
  moveBall() {
    const moveBallAnimation = this.animBuilder.build([
      animate(`1s ease`, style({
          'top': `${this.moveInputs.x}px`,
          'left': `${this.moveInputs.y}px`
      }))
    ]);
    this.animationPlayer = moveBallAnimation.create(this.moveBoxEl.nativeElement);
    this.animationPlayer.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The format for `params` on this line is incorrect:

```
moveAnimation = { value: 'start', x: 10, y: 10 };
```

It should be:

```
moveAnimation = { value: 'start', params: {x: 10, y: 10 });
```